# Is there a source for this type of proof exercises?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request

I have been studying the field axioms for a little bit and have enjoyed working on proofs using them (such as the uniqueness of zero, $x-y=x+(-y)$, etc.) Is there a source (preferably online and free) where I could find more of these exercises?  Alternatively, is there a set of problems that someone could just tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Abstract Algebra by J. B. Fraleigh includes such theorems and exercises. The exercises vary from True-false, fill in the blanks, and proofs. The exercises are arranged in increasing level of difficulty.

Comment: Love this book too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Ed" the exercises at the end of the first two sections (1.A and 1.B) contain a lot of verification of identities like you described and similar problems.